# how to write puppet class dependency on the status of another class

Tags: class, puppet

I ve two class called `main.pp` and `precheck.pp`. My idea is main.pp will continue execute if the `precheck.pp` is succeed. So, how should I get the status of `precheck.pp`

```
class my::main {
   require my::module::precheck
   # I want to execute installpackage if precheck is succeed.
   require my::module::installpackage
}
```

And in `precheck.pp`

```
class my::module::precheck {
       if $facts['osfamily'] == 'redhat' {
        if versioncmp($facts['operatingsystemmajrelease'], '7') >= 0 {
            notify {"osrelease":
                message => "${::operatingsystemmajrelease} is good to install myapp."
            }
        }
        else {
            fail("myapp is not supported on this OS release")
        }
    }
    else {
         fail("myapp is not supported on ${::osfamily}.")
    }
}
```

The above snippet is not working as expected.

thanks James

Answer (score 1):

You can create class level dependencies by utilizing the [chaining arrow syntax](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.17/lang_relationships.html#lang_rel_chaining_arrows):

```
class my::main {
  require my::module::precheck
  require my::module::installpackage
  my::module::precheck -> my::module::installpackage
}
```

This will create a dependency for the `installpackage` class container on the `precheck` class container. Note that class level dependencies in conjunction with class containers is generally not considered best practices though.